# Execute "npm" from Laravel application in Laravel Forge-Setup

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, digital-ocean, laravel-forge

I developed a tool, which generates a scss-file, runs npm run prod and uploads the generated app.css to a server.

Locally this was no problem. I simply ran `shell_exec('npm run production')` and it worked successfully.

Now, today, I rolled out the tool to a DigitalOcean-Server managed by Laravel Forge. Now, the execution of the NPM-command doesn't work anymore. Instead I see this error when running `npm run production`:

```
ERR! file sh
npm ERR! path sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm
```

When I now change the script to `npm -v` I see this:

```
6.9.0
```

Anybody know, how to get NPM running here?

(production is an alias for this command: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`)

**Update:**

Now, I tried to use yarn. Running `yarn install` worked fine. The result was expected. But running yarn run development this following error occurs:

```
2020-11-07 20:03:55 STDOUT: yarn run v1.17.3
2020-11-07 20:03:55 STDOUT: $ npm run development
2020-11-07 20:03:55 STDERR: /bin/sh: 1: 
2020-11-07 20:03:55 STDERR: npm: not found
2020-11-07 20:03:55 STDERR: error Command failed with exit code 127.
2020-11-07 20:03:55 STDOUT: info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

If I run yarn run development manually through ssh in the exact same directory, everything works fine.

**Update 2:**
I thought, maybe the problem is, that Laravel is executed by another user than me in SSH. But both are the user **forge**.

Comment: did you try deleting your node_modules/ and yarn.lock/package-lock.json files and re-running npm install?

Answer (score 3):

I've found two possible solutions for that.

One of them in a question about `shell_exec` and `npm` from a few years ago with the solution that `$PATH` doesn't include `/bin` when called as an npm script so it fails to find `/bin/sh` per `error file sh` (not my words, see [the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38698695/8394877)). Their solution was to symlink `/bin/sh` to `/usr/bin/sh`:

```
ln -s /bin/sh /usr/bin/sh
```

The other solution might be by using Symony's `Process`:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

(new Process(['npm', 'run', 'production'], base_path()))
    ->setTimeout(null)
    ->run(function ($type, $output) {
        $this->output->write($output);
    });
```

Both solutions aren't tested since I currently don't have access to a DigitalOcean server or Laravel Forge account.